# How to import a varbinary(max) column with bulk import?

Tags: sql-server, bcp, c#

I have a varbinary(max) column that I need to bulk import.  The data I'm putting into this column is a byte[] in C#.  How do I format the data in the comma-delimited file used for bulk import?  In other words, how do I convert from a byte[] to a string in a way the bcp utility will accept?

Comment: Did one of these answers work for you please?

Comment: Can you add sample data please? My answer won't work for me.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A varbinary value is of the form `0x01020304` for SQL Server to read.

So your CSV would be

```
col1,col2,varbinary
foo,1,0x01020304
bar,2,0x988776655443
```

Edit May 2013,

After testing, I can't get this to work with BULK INSERT with or without a format file.

I will post something more when I get it working. I can't delete this answer

Comment: Have you used this successfully?  On my end, I got "type mismatch" errors until I dropped the hex prefix.  "0102" was OK, "0x0101" was not.  Perhaps there is a setting somewhere which specifies which method is required.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades: hmm I can't get it to work. Playing with format files but that is not working either

Comment: Which one?  If "0x00" is what works for you, then it seems some setting differs between our setups.  If "00" is what works for you, and "0x00" does not, then we're both seeing the same thing, and it might make sense to edit your answer.

Comment: you should edit answer, as actually '0x1234' doesn't work, but '1234' does

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BCP unicode native format to import/export. Use `bcp -n` for the export and the `WITH (DATAFILETYPE='widenative')` clause for import. Click [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189941%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to read more.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. Your varbinary data must be in form `424C4F4220434F4E54454E54` in csv file. And you also must specify the right code-page of the csv file.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlobTable](
    [id] [int],
    [blobValue] [varbinary](max),
    [textValue] [nvarchar](500)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and bulk import query:

```
bulk insert dbo.BlobTable
from 'C:\importBlob.csv'
with (DATAFILETYPE = 'char', fieldterminator=',', codepage='1251')
```

It works nice for the csv file with windows-1251 encoding:

```
1,424C4F4220434F4E54454E54,english text
2,424C4F4220434F4E54454E54,русский текст
```

Here the value `424C4F4220434F4E54454E54` is simply `BLOB CONTENT` in binary form.